# What does the Ukelele do?

Tags: risk-of-rain

So I found a Ukulele, with the item description:

> ...and his music was electric

What does that mean?  What does this item do?  After reading the text again I feel like maybe it changed the game music somehow, but I've been unable to find it again since.  I also probably don't want to buy it at the item tubes without some actually helpful attributes.

What does the Ukulele do?

[image: Ukulele - ...and his music was electric]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ukelele gives a 20% chance to fire chain lightning for 4x33% damage. You can find this information yourself via the item log, which includes "Shipping Details" for all the items you pick up in the game.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think to check the item log.

Comment: @ElfSlice The item log is your friend. It contains detailed information on all the items.

Comment: Yeah, that's awesome news; I haven't looked at the logs, but I'll do so tonight!